# Spring Boot - property spring.config.location not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-properties

I have following section in application.yaml file where I am trying to read an external property file:

```
spring:
  config:
    name: my-config
    location: ./config/
```

pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.everit.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.everit.json.schema</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.10</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Config Class where I am trying to use the config:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-config-prefix")
@RefreshScope
public class MyConfig {
...
```

When I try to run the Microservice it does not map any of the config elements from the external config my-config.yml file.

If I copy and paste the entire content of the my-config.yml into application.yml file, it works as expected mapping all the elements in MyConfig class!

Spring boot seem to pick up all the elements under application.yml file for instance if I change the server.port property I can see the change when I restart however it looks like it is not picking up any properties under 'spring' element.

I have tried to supply the property on commands line and it works as expected however I want this properties in the yml file:

```
--spring.config.location=file:///Users/home/my-config.yml
```

Also, I have tried to specify the full location (as above) from application.yml file and it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manage to resolve the issue by renaming the *application.yml* file to *bootstrap.yml*.

It looks like only *bootstrap* properties can access 'spring.*' values.